# Lindenmayer system Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Sorry if this is a stupid question but I am learning python from this site:

http://interactivepython.org/courselib/static/thinkcspy/Strings/strings.html#exercises

Questions 10-14:

and I am working on the Lindenmayer system questions, I do not know what L, R, X, Y stand for.
The book already stated that 
F = forward, B = backward, - = turn left, + = turn right So what is left for L, R, X, Y?

Are they arbitrarily defined by the user?

Thanks.

Comment: They are variables within the grammar and probably have their own particular definition expressed in F, B, - and + or any of the other variables.

Comment: Then specifically for the Hilbert Curve, what do L and R represent in terms of giving instructions to the turtle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

L-systems are defined in terms of grammars. A grammar has a set of *terminals* (sometimes called *literals*), and a set of *non-terminals*.

Terminals can't be expanded, but they are executed by the turtle. Conversely, non-terminals can be expanded (and the grammar gives the rules governing the expansion), but they can't be directly executed as they aren't turtle instructions.

In an L-system, the terminals are the characters F, B, + and -, and they clearly map onto specific operations executed by the turtle. All other characters are non-terminals: they may be expanded into sequences of terminals and nonterminals according to the provided rules to increase the complexity of the figure.

So, L, R, X, Y are arbitrary names for non-terminals. We could also call them K, L, M, N and the L-system wouldn't change. Sometimes, the names are given as a hint to the symbol's role (maybe L means a "left-handed component", for instance), but sometimes they are just arbitrary (like X and Y).

Comment: Ok problem solved, L, R is just arbitrary, I just set something random like turtle.color("red") for L and turtle.color("blue") for R and it gives the Hilbert Curve.